# How to detect if an IOS app is killed, when it is not in forground. IOS7

Tags: ios, background, notifications

I know this question has been asked before, and it is stated that it cant be done.
But the APP called Këvo does this, so even if the app is in the background and the user kills it, a notification will be shown, I have tried to use localnotification, but I cant get it to work if the app is put into the background first, works fine, it app is just killed while in the foreground.

Just to clarify, the kevo key, uses BTLE in the background, advertising some btle stuff, if the user remove the app, they will notify the user that the app will not work anymore, and the door lock will not open, when you approach the door, I kind of like that notification, It is quite relevante.

Br.
Michael Rahr

Comment: Show details of how and when you create the local notification(s)

Comment: My guess is that they use a crash handler to detect the killing of the app. Then in the crash handler push a local notification.

Comment: I think you might be correct. I do like this    // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Will still send key signal";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    
    
     [application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

Answer (score 4):

My name is Steve Jablonski, I am the mobile engineer for Kevo.

You're on the right track using local notifications. We have integrated ours like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Announce App Warning
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];
    notification.alertBody = @"Your app has been shut down.";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the app maintains constant communication with the server (HTTP) and when it dies, it sends a push notification?

Local notification on dying is impossible... at the moment.

Comment: I just have to say that Kevo key does manage to do it, you can try it out. [link](http://http://www.kwikset.com/kevo/default.aspx#.U0QIBK1_sdY)

Comment: They do not use push in this case, I tried to disable all communication. Still a nice notification was shown

Comment: Slightly off topic and technically not allowed to be discussed here, but isn't that against their policy?

Comment: To clarify: using crash handler.

Comment: ok might be true, but how did kevo key then manage to get a notification to the user opon a app kill by the user, while in background ? a link to the app [link](http://www.kwikset.com/kevo/default.aspx#.U0QPEK1_sdY)

Comment: Apple aren't perfect - perhaps this one has slipped through their net.  Or perhaps it's not against apple's policies. I'm not sure, just wanted to point that out.

Comment: No problem, I would just like to know, how they did it, as the usecase is very relevante, when using BTLE, as a way to get the door opened.

Comment: More than likely they're using a crash notifier then. Try it and see if they allow it through although a word of UX caution, that might seriously annoy the users having a notification on shutdown of the app.

Comment: I agre about the notification in general, but in some case it is very relevante, and the Btle case, that Kevo uses, is one of those relevant  cases.

Comment: Fair enough, I can't comment fully as I can't see your full idea but as someone might browse this later, I wanted to highlight it for them.